# Data fetching using Spring Data JPA Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

Below is my controller

```
public class TestController {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
ProductAltRepository productAltRepository;

@GetMapping("/findAll")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void findAll() {

    Stream<ProductAltRelEntity> productAltRelEntities = productAltRepository.findAllProductAlts();
    List<ProductAltRelEntity> productAlts = Lists.newArrayList();
    productAltRelEntities.forEach(x -> {
        productAlts.add(x);
        entityManager.detach(x);
    });
    }
```

And here is the repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ProductAltRepository
        extends JpaRepository<ProductAltRelEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ProductAltRelEntity>{
@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"), @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true"), })
    @Query("SELECT p FROM ProductAltRelEntity p")
    public Stream<ProductAltRelEntity> findAllProductAlts();
}
```

Requirement is to findAll(), pagination is giving OOM, So I thought of using Stream, but getting exception.

> ```
>     [WARN] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17068, SQLState: 99999
> ```
>
> 2019-11-15 12:30:31.468 ERROR 7484 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid argument(s) in call: setFetchSize
>   [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid argument(s) in call: setFetchSize
>   2019-11-15 12:30:31.793 ERROR 7484 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] c.s.e.d.d.e.GlobalExceptionHandler       : Unhandled Exception: 
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query using scroll; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query using scroll
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query using scroll
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call: setFetchSize

Comment: If you have an OutOfMemoryException on the server when trying to load all the products from the database, what do you think would happen when a client will try to display them all? Don't try to display your whole database at once. Look at how Google works: even though it has millions of results, it only gets and displays a few ones, and allows you to get the next page if you want to.

Comment: I'm not going to display anything, it's just I need to fetch entire data and export to csv or xlsx file. I found something https://blog.madadipouya.com/2019/03/26/high-performance-data-fetching-using-spring-data-jpa-stream/

Comment: Well, apparently, the value you're trying to set for the fetch size is invalid for your database. Use a valid value.

Comment: Got it. I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the error log, you need to put the streaming code in a try block i.e

```
try(Stream<ProductAltRelEntity> productAltRelEntities = productAltRepository.findAllProductAlts()){
    List<ProductAltRelEntity> productAlts = Lists.newArrayList();
    productAltRelEntities.forEach(x -> {
        productAlts.add(x);
        entityManager.detach(x);
    });
} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Another thing I noticed is that you don't need to put @Transactional in ProductAltRepository since you already put it in TestController.

In order to stream the results we need to satisfy three conditions:

```
Forward-only resultset
Read-only statement
Fetch-size set to Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Forward-only seems to be set already by Spring Data so we don't have to do anything special about that. Your code sample already has @Transactional(readOnly = true) annotation in the TestController which is enough to satisfy the second criteria, so @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true") is not useful. The fetch-size seems useful.

Below is an extract from one of my projects:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import static org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE;

public interface IssueRepo extends JpaRepository<Issue, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Issue> {    
    
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
        @Query("select t from Issue t ")
        Stream<Issue> getAll();
    }
```

Controller

```
public class ManageIssue {
@GetMapping("all/issues")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public String getAll() {
        System.out.println("Processing Streams ...");
        try(Stream<Issue> issuesList = issueRepo.getAll()){
        
        issuesList.forEach(issue -> {
             System.out.println(issue.getId()+" Issue "+issue.getTitle());
            });
        } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        return "All";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying Integer.MIN_VALUE but it is throwing exception. Is it still working for you? Pls see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902555/how-to-monitor-spring-data-jpa-streams

Answer (score 1):

For having a look to your [source article](https://medium.com/@venkateshshukla/spring-hibernate-processing-a-huge-table-68ebad17cd08) in Medium.

I think the approach given in the article is much different than your's. You should at first open **Stateless Session**. I don't think that using the `findAll()` provided in spring-data uses that as it fetch all records from db.

Fix that would be a good start.

**BUG POSSIBLE ROOT CAUSE :**

I see that you are using `@QueryHints` your [HINT_FETCH_SIZE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html#HINT_FETCH_SIZE) is incorrect. It cannot work with Integer.MIN_VALUE as value as is equals -2^31 which is a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

Let JPA Help you in pagination, why this much extra efforts?

```
 Page<ProductAltRelEntity> productAltRelEntity= productAltRepository
                    .findAll(PageRequest.of(page - 1, 10, Sort.by("createdon").descending()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but existing functionality I'm using pagination only, the above effort is to improve the existing functionality. 
Here is something worth reading https://medium.com/@venkateshshukla/spring-hibernate-processing-a-huge-table-68ebad17cd08.