# How to monitor Spring Data JPA Streams

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I am trying to use Spring Data JPA streams using the instructions on this [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-stream/?unapproved=164796&moderation-hash=ffecd027c3954928dbd90a479b7fd657#comment-164796). However, I am unable to monitor the process or progress through any logs. Should I expect to see multiple SQL queries printed in the logs as the process tries to pull data in batches? If not, then how can I know that all of the rows are not loaded all at once?

Other blogs such as this [blog](https://medium.com/predictly-on-tech/spring-data-jpa-batching-using-streams-af456ea611fc) and [this](https://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html), suggest that I should set `HINT_FETCH_SIZE` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for MySQL and I thought it may be the solution but this throws the following exception:

> 2024-01-29 14:40:20.843  WARN 78247 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
> 2024-01-29 14:40:20.843 ERROR 78247 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@4ca63fa5 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
> END time: 48
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)

Here is my repository code:

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_READONLY, value = "true"),
})
@Query("SELECT s FROM Salary s")
Stream<Salary> findAllStream();
```

I guess I would like to get an assurance if above is the correct way to use the Stream queries in Spring Data JPA as I am unable to monitor the performance of Streaming reliabily myself?

**UPDATE**

The exception above was happening due to a duplicate call to findAllStream method in the same calling method. Removing one of them fixed the exception.

Comment: How are the transactions set in your request? If you don't specify a transaction, the stream will be closed immediately after retrieval.

Comment: Yes the calling method is annotated with @Transactional( readOnly = true), however, I have found that I was calling the findAllStream twice and removing one of the calls fixes the error that was being thrown.

Comment: Yes the calling method is annotated with @Transactional( readOnly = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any log configuration that would show me if data is being pulled in by batches. But I did find a way to test the performance locally.

In order to test the streaming capability I needed access to a database with millions of records. I used the MySQL Employees data using the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/genschsa/mysql-employees

After setting up the docker image I had problems connecting MySQL workbench with the server. It looks like the docker image is not configured to accept SSL connection which is the default setting. I had to disable the `Use SSL` flag in order to establish a connection. This setting appears under the SSL tab in MySQL workbench.

[image]

The connection string in the application must also be configure in this way:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/employees?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
```

The data in employees DB contains a table called `Salaries` that has about 2.8 million rows.

In order to test, I wrote a small Spring Data JPA application that had following methods in the repository class and a simple controller to call these:

```
@Override
List<Salary> findAll();

@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_READONLY, value = "true"),
})

@Query("SELECT s FROM Salary s")
Stream<Salary> findAllStream();
```

I then wrote a small piece of code that would convert the data read into a json object and then write back in a file using multiple threads. This was to simulate processing in a real world case.

Here is what I observed.

- When using the List method the memory usage increased significantly. The initially query took most of the time but when all of the data was loaded the actual data processing task was completed pretty quickly.
- When using the Stream method, the effect on memory usage was barely noticeable. But overall the performance to complete the processing part was similar or worse when compare with the List method.

**Conclusion**

My findings above lead me to conclude that `Stream` return type for a repository method should only be used when there is risk of running out of memory i.e. getting the `out of memory exception`. Otherwise if your application is already running on a big enough server the overall effect on memory usage would be barely noticeable and will only be temporal if your process completes quickly.

Memory usage stats from IntelliJ profiler

[image]

- Left -> When list method was run
- Right -> When stream method was run